# Sometimes JSON results keep returning null for no reason

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-maps-api-3

This is just a slight update from a question that was solved at an earlier date. I am simply trying to get 2 city names into variables from 2 different `JSON` results. This works good but every now and then one or the both sometimes returns nothing yet nothing changes?

Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to loop it until I get the result?

Sorry to be a pain but I really cannot see why its hit and miss?

The working code in `PHP` that runs the 2 queries and gets the result sometimes!

```
$p_lat = "52.406822";
$p_lng = "-1.519693";

$d_lat = "50.87626460000001";
$d_lng = "-0.3717470999999932";

$county = "";
$town = "";
$d_county = "";
$d_town = "";

$result = @file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$p_lat.",".$p_lng."&sensor=true" );
if ($result === FALSE) {
    //manage exception from file_get_contents call
} else {
    $geocodedinfo = json_decode($result);
    if ($geocodedinfo->status == "OK") {
        $county = "";
        $town = "";
        foreach ($geocodedinfo->results[0]->address_components as $addrcomps) {
            if ( $addrcomps->types[0] == 'postal_town')
                $town = $addrcomps->long_name;           
        }
    }
}

$result = @file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$d_lat.",".$d_lng."&sensor=true" );
if ($result === FALSE) {
    //manage exception from file_get_contents call
} else {
    $geocodedinfo = json_decode($result);
    if ($geocodedinfo->status == "OK") {
        $county = "";
        $d_town = "";
        foreach ($geocodedinfo->results[0]->address_components as $addrcomps) {
            if ( $addrcomps->types[0] == 'postal_town')
                $d_town = $addrcomps->long_name;           
        }
    }
}


echo $town;
echo "<br>";
echo $d_town;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed. I had to add HTTPS to it and include a KEY. I did not to start with as it was working without one!! Oh well.

```
$result = @file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$p_lat.",".$p_lng."&sensor=true&key=KEYHERE&" );
```

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to print `$result`:

```
$result = @file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$p_lat.",".$p_lng."&sensor=true" );
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($result));
exit;
```

Below is the response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error_message] => You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_
    [results] => Array
        (
        )

    [status] => OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
)
```

So try to register your application first. Which will ultimately solve your problem.

Comment: I know thanks anyway, I did not add a KEY or use HTTPS because it worked fine without it but sorted now, thanks